# Getting access token for Auth0 with Express

Tags: node.js, express, axios, auth0

in my Express app I have to get access token for Auth0. In the documentation, they have an example for pure Node JS with a request:

```js
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://XXX.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  body: '{"client_id":"XXX","client_secret":"XXX","audience":"http://localhost:3001/","grant_type":"client_credentials"}' };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

But when I'm trying to do the same in a next way:

```js
app.post('/token', function(options, res) {
  return res.json()
});
```

I'm getting "UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found".

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have enabled client_credentials grant type in your app?
Go to application / advanced / grant types and enable client_credentials

[See picture here](https://prnt.sc/r3m2a5)