# TypeError: access_token not present in TokenSet

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, openid-connect, auth0

I am trying to create a blogsite to which I have set up my authentication using auth0 and express as my backend. For the client side I am using react. To know about the info about the logged in user I need to send `req.oidc.fetchUserInfo()` object via the API.

By some research I have gotten to this point:

```
var app = express();
const { auth } = require("express-openid-connect");

...

app.use(
    auth({
        issuerBaseURL: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL,
        baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
        clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
        authRequired: false,
        auth0Logout: true,
    })
)

app.use((req,res,next) => {
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.oidc.isAuthenticated();
    next();
})


const asyncMiddleware = fn =>
  (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
      .catch(next);
  };


app.get('/user-info', asyncMiddleware(async (req, res) => {

    const userInfo = await req.oidc.fetchUserInfo();
    res.json(userInfo);
}))

...
```

Although when I go to the address localhost:5000/user-info I ran into an error:

```
GET /user-info 500 859.666 ms - 736
TypeError: access_token not present in TokenSet
    at Client.requestResource (/mnt/ALPHA/Projects/rajusite/server/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:1022:15)
    at Client.userinfo (/mnt/ALPHA/Projects/rajusite/server/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:1121:33)
    at RequestContext.fetchUserInfo (/mnt/ALPHA/Projects/rajusite/server/node_modules/express-openid-connect/lib/context.js:153:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async /mnt/ALPHA/Projects/rajusite/server/routes.js:111:22
```

I do realise this is regarding missing tokens which won't let me get the user's information.

I have checked [Getting access token for Auth0 with Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230477/getting-access-token-for-auth0-with-express) but it's already enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what scopes (like "openid email profile...") you want to have access to and in your code I don't see that.  If you don't ask for any access, then you won't get any access tokens.

See the code example [here](https://github.com/auth0/express-openid-connect/blob/d529ea0d22f09af41d303e0141d562749cba448a/EXAMPLES.md#4-obtaining-access-tokens-to-call-external-apis)

Comment: After looking at the example, I provided the scope and response_type to the authorization params and the error still persists. Also in the example it uses the req.oidc.accessToken method of RequestContext. When I tried to replicate it i received the error along the lines of :- TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'token_type' of 'req.oidc.accessToken' as it is undefined. Another noting thing would be that properties - idToken, refreshToken, idTokenClaims gives access_token not present in TokenSet error while user, isAuthenticated works fine

Comment: You need to configure the API to access in the backend, so that the scope you ask for  is mapped to what you want access to.

Comment: thanks, i figured it out. My mapping was done incorrectly

Comment: Glad you figured it out!